# How to use a variable value with spaces in a subprocess.call

Tags: python

I am reading in a variable from an external json .env file (below)

```
{
"response-dashboard-repo": "/Users/derekm/BGGoPlan Home/99.0 Repo/Response/response-dashboard",
"responsemobile-repo": "/Users/derekm/BGGoPlan Home/99.0 Repo/BGGoPlan-Lite/NON-SSO-Response/bg3-lite-2020"
}
```

The problem is both key:values have spaces as part of their values. (eg. 99.0 Repo)

I want to use this value in a subprocess command, but Python keeps breaking it up based on spaces.

```
# load environment data
  with open(envPath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as envFile:
      envData = json.load(envFile)

  repo_location = envData['response-dashboard-repo']

# Note: The variable repo_loc is read in from an env file:
subprocess.run(repo_location + '/scripts/buildDashboards.pl', shell=True)
```

But when I run my script, Python keeps saying:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/derekm/BGGoPlan: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a list with one item.  And you don't need a shell with this command.

```
subprocess.run([repo_location + '/scripts/buildDashboards.pl'])
```

Comment: Thanks TIm.  But how do I gracefully handle errors though (bad pathname, etc).  When I run that command with a wrong path (failure path testing), I just get an ugly Traceback.  Is there a way to hide the error and only get back an error code which I can respond to?

Comment: You can certainly validate the path before you launch.  It's dangerous to run an arbitrary command read from a file that's not under your control -- that's an easy hack target.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
# Note: The variable repo_loc is read in from an env file:
repo_location = repo_location(" ", "\ ")
subprocess.run(repo_location + '/scripts/buildDashboards.pl', shell=True)
```